# Gdal Read Geodatabase Features Don't Show Object ID

Tags: gdal, node-js, objectid

I am using [Gdal Node.js interface](https://github.com/naturalatlas/node-gdal) to read features of a layer from a Esri Geodatabase. My javascript code looks like this:

```
var dataset = gdal.open(inputPath);
var layer = dataset.layers.get(layerName);
layer.features.forEach(function (feature, featureId) {
    var geom;
    var recordId = null;
    var routeId = null;
    try {
        var geomWKB = feature.getGeometry().toWKB();
        var geomWKBString = geomWKB.toString("hex");
        geom = geomWKBString;
        if (recordColumn) {
            let names = feature.fields.getNames();
            recordId = feature.fields.get(recordColumn);
        }
       if (routeIdColumn) {
           routeId = feature.fields.get(routeIdColumn);
       }
    }
    catch (err) {
    }
    ......   
});
```

This layer has 12 fields. However, gdal only gets 11 fields missing OBJECTID when extract fields of a feature. Therefore `recordId = feature.fields.get('OBJECTID')` does not work.

I inspected the layer and noticed OBJECTID was assigned to FIDColumn, which means gdal can access to OBJECTID field but doesn't add it to features' schema.

What could cause the issue?

Comment: I guess that OBJECTID is a fid field that is not exposed as a normal attribute. GetFID seems to be for reading it http://www.gdal.org/classOGRFeature.html#a696f6e0c7f9a7025020b8ecf71cbd7a8. I thing I would try to use SQL in ExecuteSQL http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.DataSource-class.html#ExecuteSQL for reading the features, something like  `select geometry,  OBJECTID as id_attribute, attr_1, attr_2 from my_layer`

Comment: @user30184 Thank you for the response. The problem is that my code used to be working for exactly same scenario last week. I have to make sure gdal providing consistent output. Hope we can get some solid source regarding how gdal handle 'OBJECTID'. The reason I don't use query is that I don't know how many fields there will be. Therefore I have to make the process dynamic and flexible.

Comment: There was a change recently that changed the default or "preserve_fid" to "yes" in ogr2ogr. This may be related. Search an option that forces GDAL to create a new fid and have a try.

Comment: Probably this is the reason. Do you know how to add this option when using [node-gdal](https://github.com/naturalatlas/node-gdal)? I am new to this library and have never added any option.

Comment: How about checking the fid column with layer.GetFIDColumn http://www.gdal.org/classOGRLayer.html#af0cb9a05310d7b17d9dfec9e83a18e61 and then using SQL as `select *, my_fid_column as fid_attribute`? In your case `select *, OBJECTID` should work because I guess that geodatabase has always the same name for fid.

Comment: Currently I am using the value of FIDColumn as you adviced. It is easier for me to deploy than SQL. Thanks!